# Checkout payment - implementation -frontend

Tags: payment-gateway, checkout, payment-processing

I have to implement checkout payment, is it possible on frontend, when we click on button 'pay' to show dialog for payment data, any help will be welcome, and what means client_id and client_secret

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using JavaScript. But if you're planning to implement it only on frontend it will be just like a template and no real payments will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement it using a **hosted payment page**. Read this documentation page to get [more information](https://www.checkout.com/docs/payments/accept-payments/accept-a-payment-on-a-hosted-page/manage-your-hosted-payments-page)

Basically what you do, you make an API request and get an hosted page URL in response. That link can be opened in the browser to take payments.